# How to use "Docker Quickstart Terminal" to start another docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

On my mac, when I start docker by running "Docker quickstart terminal", it will start the `default` docker machine.

I see in the `start.sh` of the docker quickstart terminal is:

```
#!/bin/bash

VM=default
DOCKER_MACHINE=/usr/local/bin/docker-machine
VBOXMANAGE=/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage

BLUE='\033[0;34m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m'

... more
```

How can I start another docker machine without modifying this shell file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply  can [create a new docker machin](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/)e:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 --virtualbox-disk-size 204800 my_new_machine
```

(replace my_new_machine)

Then you [can ssh to it](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/):

```
docker-machine start my_new_container
eval $($DOCKER_MACHINE env my_new_container --shell=bash)
docker-machine ssh my_new_container
```

Comment: Seems like the "docker quickstart terminal" just a handy tool to use the `default` docker machine, I should use `docker-machine` if I want more controls, thanks!

Comment: what this command does ?  eval $($DOCKER_MACHINE env my_new_container --shell=bash) 

I am receiving an error: " eval is not a recognized command..."

Comment: @guilhermecgs What is your OS? The goal is to set the variables which are displayed by `docker-machine env`. See https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/ for alternative to eval for Mac and Windows.

Comment: I am using windows. So, this command is setting the "shell" enviroment variable to value "bash".  In windows would something like:  docker-machine env my_new_container --shell=bash   ??

Comment: @guilhermecgs As documented in https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/env/, use in a regular CMD session: `docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd dev` (replace `dev` by the name of your docker machine, and you still need to copy and paste the result in said CMD session). Or use Powershell (in a Powershell session): `docker-machine.exe env --shell=powershell dev | Invoke-Expression`

Comment: @guilhermecgs I generally don't even bother with those, I just `docker-machine ssh` (https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/) to my machine, and execute docker commands directly in that ssh session. `docker-machine env` is there if you don't ssh to the machine, and want to execute docker commands to said machine.