# Using Docker Kitematic, how can I switch to different docker machine?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I'm new to Docker (just started learning today).
I'm using docker 1.9.1 on MacOSX 10.10.5.

Apparently, there's this new "docker-machine" tool that replaces the deprecated "boot2docker". I'm not really sure what either are, but since docker-machine is so new, there doesn't seem to be a lot out there or people experiencing my specific set of issues.

Anyways, I'm at the point where I believe I created a VM using docker-machine:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 my_machine
```

As far as I understand, I now have two docker virtual machines, the "default" one and a "my_machine".
(I thought Docker was different from vagrant in that it didn't use virtual machines but maybe that's a lesson for another day).

Under ~/.docker/machine/machines, I have both a default/ and my_machine/ folder

When I launch Kitematic (as a MacOSX app), I believe it's launching a view into the "default" virtual machine. The reasons I believe this are because

1. When I launch the Docker CLI from Kitematic and I echo $DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME in the CLI, it prints "default" as opposed to "my_machine"
2. Also, when I switch into "my_machine" (by typing eval "$(docker-machine env my_machine)") and create a new docker container (e.g. "docker build -t my_instance"), it doesn't show up in Kitematic.

So question is, how can I get Kitematic to "switch" to my newly created virtual machine.

Sorry, if what I'm saying doesn't make a whole lot of sense. I may not be using the right docker lingo at all. I'm happy to clarify and edit this post as I learn though.

I noticed in a similar post, someone was trying to [switch to a different docker-machine from the Docker Quickstart Terminal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34262555/how-to-use-docker-quickstart-terminal-to-start-another-docker-machine). Curious if there's a similar answer for switching the Kitematic app

Comment: My workaround is to remove the original "default" host and create my new host with the "default" name. Kitematic seems to be keyed into this "default"-named host